# how to create a loop to read line by line from a csv file

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, while-loop

good night friends, i'm new to python and i need help to create a loop to read line by line from a csv file, any ideas?

my code :

```
file = csv.reader(open('amino_acids.csv'), delimiter = ';')
next(file)
for [Link, Titulo, DSNStockCod, SKU, DIMENSIONS, Weight, Price, Description, Directions, Warnings, Url_Imagem] in arquivo:
    print (str(Titulo))
```

Answer (score 1):

Where is "arquivo" coming from? I think you need to start reading the file like this:

```
for line in file:
```

Inside that loop, you can write code to accomplish whatever it is you're trying to do. I am a little bit confused because your file suggests it contains amino acid data, but the list in your for loop is seemingly unrelated.

Answer (score 0):

Convert each row to a tuple then deconstruct to variables.

```
file = csv.reader(open('amino_acids.csv'), delimiter = ';')

for row in file:
    Link, Titulo, DSNStockCod, SKU, DIMENSIONS, Weight, Price, Description, Directions, Warnings, Url_Imagem = tuple(row)
    print (str(Titulo))
```